# Error with strided slice in tensorflow lite

Tags: c++, tensorflow-lite, quantization

I'm facing a problem with tensorflow-lite. I get this error:

> Type INT32 (2) not supported.
> Node STRIDED_SLICE (number 2) failed to invoke with status 1

What I did was:

I trained a model with MNIST data.

```
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Reshape(target_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=12, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])
```

I converted the model using **integer-only quantization**. However, when I invoke the model it
throws that error.

I was looking at the striced_slice.cc and I found this:

```cpp
      switch (output->type) {
        case kTfLiteFloat32:
          reference_ops::StridedSlice(op_params,
                                      tflite::micro::GetTensorShape(input),
                                      tflite::micro::GetTensorData<float>(input),
                                      tflite::micro::GetTensorShape(output),
                                      tflite::micro::GetTensorData<float>(output));
          break;
        case kTfLiteUInt8:
          reference_ops::StridedSlice(
              op_params, tflite::micro::GetTensorShape(input),
              tflite::micro::GetTensorData<uint8_t>(input),
              tflite::micro::GetTensorShape(output),
              tflite::micro::GetTensorData<uint8_t>(output));
          break;
        case kTfLiteInt8:
          reference_ops::StridedSlice(op_params,
                                      tflite::micro::GetTensorShape(input),
                                      tflite::micro::GetTensorData<int8_t>(input),
                                      tflite::micro::GetTensorShape(output),
                                      tflite::micro::GetTensorData<int8_t>(output));
          break;
        default:
          TF_LITE_KERNEL_LOG(context, "Type %s (%d) not supported.",
                             TfLiteTypeGetName(input->type), input->type);
```

So there is not support for int32. I am not really sure how I can handle this kind of problem. Is there any way to change the behavior on this node? Should I do something different in the quantization step?

What I did was:

```
def representative_data_gen():
  for input_value in tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_images).batch(1).take(100):
    yield [input_value]

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.representative_dataset = representative_data_gen
# Ensure that if any ops can't be quantized, the converter throws an error
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter.inference_input_type = tf.int8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.int8

tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("model_int8.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

PD: I'm working with tensorflow-lite to be used in stm32.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May you share tflite model please?

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/285bed153563fefbf6f0e048755276f020201116202042/e906e3 here the tflite model

Comment: Where did the int32 error occurred and are you running TFLite or TFLite for microcontrollers? As @AlexK. mentioned that full integer quantization uses int8 not int32 so it's intended that you don't see int32 in the code

Comment: Checked your tflite model, it has an issue. Branch "shape"->"strided slice"->"pack" looks strange to me and I do not see corresponding part of it in your keras model. It looks like you have not set shape for reshape op by constant value. Maybe try to use reshape as first layer by specifying `input_shape`

Comment: You can check tflite model yourself with instrument like Netron. For full-int8 quantization model is valid has only int8 inputs-outputs-ops

Comment: Hello @Tiezhen. I'm running tflite for microcontrollers. I'm really new to this subject. I just found [this colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/g3doc/performance/post_training_integer_quant.ipynb#scrollTo=BEY59dC14uRv) and I got with it. So, I check the model in NetronApp and I see that there are some layers with int32 as input. So, you said that all the layers must be in int8, don't you?

Comment: @r142431 another option try to specify batch explicitly in Keras, lets say with 1.

Answer (score 0):

When you perform full-integer quantization, your inputs and outputs should be 1-byte long (in your case int8). Give as input int8 values and you will be able to invoke your model.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. I'm using input with 1 byte long. The problem seems to be in another layer.

Comment: If model fully quantized we will not find any type other than int8 inside even if used 16bit weights. So the only type-related issue can be while feeding input and output objects. Please carefully check your input and output objects.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this issue simply adding INT32 support to striced_slice.cc.

```
case kTfLiteFloat32:
  reference_ops::StridedSlice(op_params,
                              tflite::micro::GetTensorShape(input),
                              tflite::micro::GetTensorData<float>(input),
                              tflite::micro::GetTensorShape(output),
                              tflite::micro::GetTensorData<float>(output));
  break;
case kTfLiteUInt8:
  reference_ops::StridedSlice(
      op_params, tflite::micro::GetTensorShape(input),
      tflite::micro::GetTensorData<uint8_t>(input),
      tflite::micro::GetTensorShape(output),
      tflite::micro::GetTensorData<uint8_t>(output));
  break;
case kTfLiteInt8:
  reference_ops::StridedSlice(op_params,
                              tflite::micro::GetTensorShape(input),
                              tflite::micro::GetTensorData<int8_t>(input),
                              tflite::micro::GetTensorShape(output),
                              tflite::micro::GetTensorData<int8_t>(output));
  break;
case kTfLiteInt32:
  reference_ops::StridedSlice(op_params,
                              tflite::micro::GetTensorShape(input),
                              tflite::micro::GetTensorData<int8_t>(input),
                              tflite::micro::GetTensorShape(output),
                              tflite::micro::GetTensorData<int8_t>(output));
  break;
default:
  TF_LITE_KERNEL_LOG(context, "Type %s (%d) not supported.",
                     TfLiteTypeGetName(input->type), input->type);
  return kTfLiteError;
```

I copied the **kTfLiteInt8** case and created a **kTfLiteInt32** case.

The idea is since I know the input data is actually int8 type, I simply cast it to int8.

I have tested it in an ESP32 microcontroller. I didn't run a full set of test but with a few samples it worked as expected.

This is a workaround. The real fix should be done in the converter where it fully quantize the model by using TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8. Somehow, it quantize the float32 types but int32 stays in one of the layers.