# Tensorflow Lite LSTM Model for Microprocessors on ESP32, "Type INT32 (2) not supported"

Tags: esp32, tflite

The Current error, seen when running the model on the ESP32 (An Adafruit ESP32 Huzzah):

```
Type INT32 (2) not supported.
Node ADD (number 4) failed to invoke with status 1
Node WHILE (number 2) failed to invoke with status 1
```

**Preamble**

Currently developing a system to predict future movement in a person using an ESP32 connected to several sensors. The system's intent is to use 20 samples taken over the previous 20 cycles from 8 sensors to create a 20x8 Snapshot that is fed into a Tensorflow Lite LSTM Model. This outputs a 1x10 array containing what it thinks will be the position of the wearer's leg for the next 10 cycles. I Have had previous experience with a stateful Convolutional Neural Network, using EloquentTinyML to simplify the process. That worked fine, however that does not seem to work with LSTM models.

The Tensorflow Model:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    Input(shape=(20,8), name="Input"),
    LSTM(units=48, return_sequences=True, activation='relu', unroll=False),
    LSTM(units=16, return_sequences=False, activation='relu',unroll=False),
    layers.Flatten(),
    Dense(units=pred, name="output")
    ])
```

By default this model takes in float32 values normalised between -1 and 1.

The Process of conversion from generating the model in Python using Keras and Tensorflow to TFLite:

```
def representative_data_gen():
    samples = int(data_train.shape[0]/10) #generate 1/10th of data_train as samples
    rSamp = rd.sample(range(data_train.shape[0]), samples) #randomly choose array values within data_train
    i = 0
    for i in rSamp: #for each chosen array value within data_train
        yield[data_train[i].astype(np.float32)]#yield data at that array value

run_model = tf.function(lambda x: model(x))
BATCH_SIZE = 1 
STEPS = 20 #fails if not 20
INPUT_SIZE = 8 #fails if not 8
concrete_func = run_model.get_concrete_function(tf.TensorSpec([BATCH_SIZE, STEPS, INPUT_SIZE], model.inputs[0].dtype))

# model directory.
MODEL_DIR = "keras_lstm"
model.save(MODEL_DIR, save_format="tf", signatures=concrete_func)

print("saved")
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(MODEL_DIR)
#converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.representative_dataset = representative_data_gen #required to quantise to int8
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter.inference_input_type = tf.int8  
converter.inference_output_type = tf.int8  
tflite_model = converter.convert()

open(fileLoc+fileName, "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

This code saves the model as in SavedModel.pb format, then loads it and converts it to .tflite format, the use of "converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]" and setting inference_input_type = tf.int8 was an attempt to force the model to accept int8 rather than float32, it doesn't seem to work. The code is not entirely my own work, taking inspiration from [Here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/experimental_new_converter/Keras_LSTM_fusion_Codelab.ipynb) and [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization) (

the .tflite model is then converted to a header file using vim and xxd, EG:

```
xxd -i modelLSTM4816_10.tflite > exoLSTM4816_10q.h
```

In order to implement this model into the ESP 32 I am using the [tflite-micro ESP Examples Library](https://github.com/espressif/tflite-micro-esp-examples). This code is also used to draw inspiration from.

All Relevant Code for the Model and ESP32 can be found [Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1lExXH1mmNFC1bOwVJ564_nOGQN5YbApC?usp=sharing)

[ESP Code contains all libraries, relevant code is within /src]
Data is fed into the model as a 160-length array.

**The Error**

The Current Error occurs when using interpreter->Invoke(). Giving the error:

```
Type INT32 (2) not supported.
Node ADD (number 4) failed to invoke with status 1
Node WHILE (number 2) failed to invoke with status 1
```

My assumption has been this error relates to the model not accepting float32 data, which led to the model being Quantised to int8 format. I Have confirmed the model input and output are in int8 format via Retron, and the data fed into it is of int8_t format. Yet the error remains.

My second assumption is that it relates in some what to Node ADD and Node WHILE, a post with a very similar issue [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64850356/error-with-strided-slice-in-tensorflow-lite) has errors involving "STRIDED SLICE" instead of "ADD" and "WHILE", these seem to be Built-In Operators called by the AllOpsResolver. add.cc seems to have conditions for different input types (int8, float32, etc), it seems to not recognise my model being in int8 format, having a case for "kTfLiteInt8", which is equal to 9 to represent int8, despite this checking my model's input and output types with model_input->type and model_output->type a 9 is produced in both instances.

Despite the errors, I do get outputs, however the 10 predictions I get are just the first 10 input values.

I've spent about 2-3 weeks on trying to convert an LSTM model to work on an ESP32 and have run out of patience and ideas. Any Assistance would be appreciated.

A Dump of my ESP32 Code for quick reference:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/all_ops_resolver.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_interpreter.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/system_setup.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/schema/schema_generated.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/tflite_bridge/micro_error_reporter.h"

//network C files, only include one at a time
//#include "exoConv3224_10.h" //Conv1D network
//#include "exoLSTM3216_10_Rolled.h" //unrolled, default LSTM option
//include "exoLSTM3216_10_UnRoll.h" //rolled, non default LSTM option
//#include "exoLSTM48_10.h" //rolled, simple LSTM
#include "exoLSTM4816_10q.h" //quantised simple LSTM
#include "exoMoveIdeal.h"

namespace {
    const tflite::Model* model = nullptr;
    tflite::MicroInterpreter* interpreter = nullptr;
    TfLiteTensor* model_input = nullptr;
    TfLiteTensor* model_output = nullptr;
    //FeatureProvider* feature_provider = nullptr;
    //RecognizeCommands* recognizer = nullptr;
    int32_t previous_time = 0;

    // Create an area of memory to use for input, output, and intermediate arrays.
    // The size of this will depend on the model you're using, and may need to be
    // determined by experimentation.
    constexpr int kFeatureSliceSize = 20; //number of samples per sensor
    constexpr int kFeatureSliceCount = 8; //number of sensors
    constexpr int kFeatureElementCount = (kFeatureSliceSize * kFeatureSliceCount); //total number of elements

    constexpr int kTensorArenaSize = 80 * 1024; //vary this with model size
    uint8_t tensor_arena[kTensorArenaSize];
    float feature_buffer[kFeatureElementCount]; //store features in buffer
    int8_t* model_input_buffer = nullptr;
}  // namespace

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println("Loading Tensorflow model....");
    model = tflite::GetModel(model_data); //get the model
    Serial.println("Model Loaded");

    tflite::AllOpsResolver resolver; //could use limited Micro_ops_resolver and define specific future bits
    static tflite::MicroInterpreter static_interpreter(model, resolver, tensor_arena, kTensorArenaSize);
    Serial.println("Resolver");
    interpreter = &static_interpreter;
    TfLiteStatus allocate_status = interpreter->AllocateTensors();
    Serial.println("Allocated Tensors");
    if (allocate_status != kTfLiteOk) 
    {
        Serial.println("AllocateTensors() failed");
        Serial.println(allocate_status); //print status
        return;
    }
    
    model_input = interpreter->input(0);
    model_output = interpreter->output(0); //get outputs
    //model_input->dims->data[0] = 8;
    //model_input->dims->data[1] = 160;
    //model_input->dims->size = 2;
    Serial.println(model_input->dims->size); //output 3, should be 2?
    Serial.println(model_input->dims->data[0]); //output 1, correct?
    Serial.println(model_input->dims->data[1]); //20
    Serial.println(model_input->dims->data[2]); //8
    //Serial.println(model_input->type); //type, int8 outputs a 9
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("Create Buffer");
    //model_input_buffer = model_input->data.int8; //give model_input_buffer an address where data will be placed
    Serial.printf("%p\n",(void *)model_input_buffer);

    //delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Fill Buffer");
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < 160; i++) //add from test array to buffer, should be 160
    { //ideally input data should be normalised between -1 and 1, not sure how that would be compatible with int8? Replace -1 to 1 with -128 to 127?
        if(i%8==0) //Seperate out each sample on print
            Serial.print("| ");
        //model_input_buffer[i] = mTestq2[i]; //160-length list of int8 values
        model_input->data.int8[i] = mTestq2[i];  //160-length list of int8 values
        Serial.printf("%d ",model_input->data.int8[i]);

    }

    Serial.println("\nInvoke");
    interpreter->Invoke(); //do network stuff, current fails from invalid INT32 type
    Serial.println("Get Output");

    model_output = interpreter->output(0); //get outputs
    Serial.println(model_output->type); //type, int8 outputs a 9
    Serial.println(model_output->dims->size);//print output pointer data
    Serial.println(model_output->dims->data[0]); //1x10 output, as it should be
    Serial.println(model_output->dims->data[1]);
    Serial.println("Print Predictions");
    //Serial.printf("%p\n",(void *)model_output);
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) //output 10 predictions, currently just outputs first 10 inputs as no processing done to it
    {
        Serial.printf("%d, ", model_output->data.int8[i]);
    }
    

}

void loop() //repeats basic loop of recognition, still fails
{
    int i = 0;
    delay(1000);
    for(i = 0; i < 160; i++) //add from test array to buffer, should be 160
    { //ideally input data should be normalised between -1 and 1, not sure how that would be compatible with int8? Replace -1 to 1 with -128 to 127?
        //model_input_buffer[i] = mTestq2[i]; //160-length list of int8 values
        model_input->data.int8[i] = mTestq2[i];  //160-length list of int8 values
    }
    interpreter->Invoke(); //do network stuff, current fails from invalid INT32 type
    model_output = interpreter->output(0); //get outputs
    Serial.println("Print Predictions");
    //Serial.printf("%p\n",(void *)model_output);
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) //output 10 predictions, currently just outputs first 10 inputs as no processing done to it
    {
        Serial.printf("%d, ", model_output->data.int8[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Issues has a potential solution: see [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tflite-micro/issues/1825#issuecomment-1475385127).
Essentially, a patch must be applied to the add.cc file, currently TF-Micro library and by extension the TF-Micro-ESP-Examples library's ADD OP does not properly support INT32. It's possible this might change in the future.